# Material Ui layout Grid adjusting height to middle of the page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following material UI grid code (copied from their documentation and adjusted to show the problem I'm having):

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  tall: {
    height: 400,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container>
      <Grid item container xs={4}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.tall}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container xs={8}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue I am having is that it is adjusting the height of the second column based on the first column, as you can see in the image below. I'd like the xs=6 tiles in the second column to be directly stacked one on top of the other. How do I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding to the highest grid container: alignItems="baseline" seems to have done the trick